# gdal.Warp cutline creates empty file when run on the server, but works perfectly fine through Python command line

Tags: gdal, python-2.7, gdalwarp

Trying to cut geotif with a shp file.

When I open Python command line interpreter and run

```
from osgeo import gdal

gdal.Warp(outfile, infile,format='GTiff', cutlineDSName=shpfile,  srcSRS='EPSG:4326', dstSRS='EPSG:4326', dstNodata=-9999)
```

it creates the geotif as expected, though shows following output:

```
Warning 1: for band 1, destination nodata value has been clamped to 0, the original value being out of range.
<osgeo.gdal.Dataset; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'GDALDatasetShadow *' at 0x7f8c72ac5b10> >
```

When I do the same within a web server, doing file preparation (projection, transparency, etc.) first with gdal and then trying to cut the file with the same command I get an empty file (0 bytes) and server (gunicorn) restarts.

Machine:

```
Linux Mint 18.3
```

Libraries versions:

```
gdal==2.2.2
proj==4.9.3
geos==3.6.2
python==2.7.12
gunicorn==19.7.1
```

Does anyone have any idea how to make it working in the web server environment?

Answer (score 1):

After reinstalling the whole system with:

```
proj==4.9.2
gdal==2.1.3
```

everything started to work like a charm.